# How to replace $ with $`?

Tags: atom-editor

I try to replace the dollar sign with a dollar sign and a backtick but the backtick doesn't show up if there is no space between the two symbols.

**Does work**

Search: `(\$)` (Regex activated)

Replace: $ `

**Does not work**

Search: `(\$)` (Regex activated)

Replace: $`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ has a special meaning in Regex so you have to write $$` if you want to replace something with "dollar sign backtick". Explanation @ [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN)